# Implement Video Stream in Java?

Tags: java, swing, video-streaming

Is there a way to implement a video stream like [twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv) in Java to display the video in a GUI ?

Comment: Much too broad. Short but useless answer would be "yes, there is" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: You need to implement a protocol which is suitable for transmitting video data on the fly. That means that there has to be some kind of receiver. Most likely, you want to stream to different clients at the same time, so sending the data to a server first and then spreading it to all clients would be the way to go.
Creating a fully working and efficient protocol is a hard job, that's why it would be the smartest idea to use an existing protocol. As far as I know, Twitch uses the [RTMP (Real Time Messaging Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)

If you do some research about this, you will find some libraries that you can use in your Java program, but even with a finished protocol and library, it's not an easy job. Before you try to design a streaming service/client/whatever, you should start doing much of research.